# time regex for 12hr am and pm

Tags: c#, regex

I have made this regex

```
 ^(00|0[0-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9]? ((a|p)m|(A|P)M)$
```

but the problem is it is accepting 
00:00 am which i dont want to be like this
how to ignore?
I want time to be in this format
12:12 am
it should not be in this 
00:21 am
I am using this code for validation

```
        private bool valtime()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("^(00|0[0-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9]? ((a|p)m|(A|P)M)$");
        if (regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just make your digit matching start at 1 for the hours? i.e. `[1-9]` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: Why have you *explicitly* got `00` at the start of your regex if you don't want to accept it?

Comment: Why is there a question mark after `[0-9]`? That way you allow the minutes to be 0 to 5 or 00 to 59.

Comment: And there surely is a IgnoreCase option for Regexes in C#, so that you don't have to list all the alternatives for am/pm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [ap]m$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```